# How can I execute JavaScript code from Delphi using TMS Web Core?

Tags: javascript, delphi, alert, tms, tms-web-core

I've created a simple app with a `TWebEdit` and a `TWebButton` on it. I want to call/execute a JavaScript `alert()` function from within the button that will alert the text from the `TWebEdit`.

How can I do this?

Obviously, I can't just do the following code as this isn't valid Delphi:

```
procedure TForm2.WebButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  alert(WebEdit1.Text);
end;
```

How can JavaScript code be called from within this button click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call JavaScript code directly within Delphi using the `asm` code block:

```
procedure TForm2.WebButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AlertText: String;
begin
  AlertText := WebEdit1.Text;

  asm
    alert(AlertText);
  end;
end;
```

That would work as can be seen by the below screenshots:

[image: Delphi TMS Web Core app doing a JavaScript alert]

[image: Delphi TMS Web Core app doing a JavaScript alert]

---

Here's another example with linebreaks:

```
procedure TForm2.WebButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AlertText: String;
begin
  AlertText := WebEdit1.Text;

  asm
    alert('Your entered text is: \n\n' + AlertText);
  end;
end;
```

[image: Delphi TMS Web Core app doing a JavaScript alert]

Answer (score 3):

TMS Web Core has three global variables that you can use to access the commonly used functionality of the `document`, `window` and `console` objects in JavaScript.

This is how they are declared as global variables in the `Web` unit:

```
var
  document: TJSDocument;
  window: TJSWindow;
  console: TJSConsole;
```

Using these global variables, you can access most functionality within these objects directly from your Delphi code.

For example:

```
procedure TForm8.WebButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  document.title := 'Hello World!';
  window.alert(document.title);
end;
```